# Phone catalogue in MIPS Assembly, problem with printing entries

Tags: assembly, mips

I am making a phone catalogue in MIPS, but i have a problem with getting the elements I input with every recursion. The function Print_Entry is used when the mode [I] (inquiry) is chosen to retrieve a previous entry I've made. But when i make a new entry the elements of the previous entry get overwritten by the latest ones I've inserted. Each element takes up 20 characters of the memory. Can anyone explain why the program doesn't keep the elements of previous entries?

```
    .data

menu: .asciiz "\nPlease determine operation, Entry[E],Inquiry[I] ,Quit[Q]: \n"
get_first: .asciiz "\nPlease enter first name: \n"
get_last: .asciiz "\nPlease enter last name: \n"
get_num: .asciiz "\nPlease enter phone number: \n"
entry_submission: .asciiz "\nThank you, the new entry is the following: "
find_contact: .asciiz "\nPlease enter the entry number you wish to retrieve: "
not_found: .asciiz "\nThere is no such entry in the phonebook"
print_contact: .asciiz "\nThe number is: "
error_message: .asciiz "\nWrong input, please try again\n"
space1: .asciiz "\n"
space2: .asciiz ".\n"
.align 2
last_name: .space 20
first_name: .space 20
phone_num: .space 20
phonebook: .space 600

.text

main:

    la $s1,phonebook    #Set address to phonebook in $s1
    addu $s4, $zero, $s1
    ori $s2, $zero, 0 #Index for how many times we have executed Get_Entry
    sub_main:

        #E=69   I=73    Q=81 (ascii codes)
        #Call function Prompt_User
        jal Prompt_User

        beq $s0,69,x
        beq $s0,73,y
        beq $s0,81,z

        #Print "Wrong input try again" if it isn't one of the 3 letters
        ori $v0, $zero, 4
        la $a0, error_message
        syscall

        j sub_main

        x:
        #Call function Get_Entry
        jal Get_Entry
        j sub_main

        y:
        #Call function Print_Entry
        jal Print_Entry
        j sub_main

        z:
        #Terminate the programm
        ori $v0, $zero, 10
        syscall




Prompt_User:

    #print "Please determine operation, Entry[E],Inquiry [I] ,Quit [Q]: \n"
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, menu
    syscall

    #Get users input
    ori $v0, $zero, 12 #call=12=read character
    syscall

  #Save user's choice in $s0
    addu $s0, $zero, $v0

    jr $ra

Get_Entry:

    addi $sp, $sp, -4   # enlarge the stack, to make room for one word
  sw $ra, 0($sp)        # save return address to stack

    addu $s5, $zero, $s4

    jal Last_Name       #Asks for the Last Name from user
    addi $s4,20
    jal First_Name      #Asks for the First Name from user
    addi $s4,20
    jal Phone_Number    #Asks for the Phone Number from user
    addi $s4,20

    #Prints "Thank you, the new entry is the following: "
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, entry_submission
    syscall

    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, space1
    syscall


    #Prints index
    ori $v0, $zero, 1
    addu $a0, $zero, $s2
    syscall

    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, space2
    syscall

    #Prints Last Name
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    lw $a0, 0($s5)
    syscall

    #Prints first name
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    lw $a0, 20($s5)
    syscall

    #Prints phone number
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    lw $a0, 40($s5)
    syscall


    addi $s2,$s2,1      #Progress counter of Get_Entry executions

    lw $ra, 0($sp)      # load return address to stack

    addi $sp, $sp, 4    # shrink the stack to its former size
    jr $ra

Last_Name:

    #Ask for last name
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, get_last
    syscall

    #Read user's input
    ori $a1, $zero, 20
    ori $v0, $zero, 8
    la $a0,last_name
    syscall

    la $t0, last_name       #Load address of user's input in $t0
    sw $t0, 0($s4)          #Store user's string in phonebook


    jr $ra

First_Name:

    #Ask for first name
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, get_first
    syscall

    #Read user's input
    ori $a1, $zero, 20
    ori $v0, $zero, 8
    la $a0,first_name
    syscall

    la $t0, first_name      #Load address of user's input in $t0
    sw $t0, 0($s4)          #Store user's string in phonebook

    jr $ra

Phone_Number:

    #Ask for Phone Number
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, get_num
    syscall

    #Read user's input
    ori $a1, $zero, 20
    ori $v0, $zero, 8
    la $a0,phone_num
    syscall

    la $t0,phone_num        #Load address of user's input in $t0
    sw $t0, 0($s4)          #Store user's string in phonebook

    jr $ra

Print_Entry:

    #Print "Please enter the entry number you wish to retrieve:"
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, find_contact
    syscall

    #Get user's choice
    ori $v0, $zero, 5
    syscall
    addu $t8, $zero, $v0

    #Check if user's input is less than 0
    slt $t7, $t8, $0
    bne $t7, $zero, exit
    #Check if user's input is greater than the number of entries in the catalog
    slt $t7, $s2, $t8
    bne $t7, $zero, exit

    addi $t1,$zero,60
  mul $t9, $t8, $t1
    addu $s3, $s1, $t9

    #Print "The number is:"
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, print_contact
    syscall

    #Print Last name of registration
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    lw $a0, 0($s3)
    syscall

    #Print First name of registration
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    lw $a0, 20($s3)
    syscall

    #Print phone number of registration
    ori $v0, $zero, 4
    lw $a0, 40($s3)
    syscall


    jr $ra

    exit:

        #Print "There is no such entry in the phonebook"
        ori $v0, $zero, 4
        la $a0, not_found
        syscall

    jr $ra
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using single step to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Yes, I tried observing the behavior of the address pointers using breakpoints and they behave like they should.

Comment: You have to single step the whole program to find the first instruction that diverges from what you expect.

Comment: `la $t0,phone_num` / `sw $t0, 0($s4)  #Store user's string in phonebook`.   You're storing a pointer to the same static buffer every time, not copying the string data into a record inside the `phonebook` array.  This is like C `static char phone_num[20];` / read into `phone_num` / `phonebook[i].num = &phone_num[0];`, not `memcpy`.  You could read input directly into the right place in the `phonebook` array when taking a new entry.